# Protractor throwing error now that ng-app directive is on html tag

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, protractor

So recently the developers I work with moved the ng-app directive from the body tag to the html tag, in the application we are working on. I am building the end to end test suite using protractor since we are currently using Angular 1.4.8

Before this morning everything in all of my tests ran successfully, however now that the ng-app directive is on the html tag I am getting the following error.

```
 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/async/nexttick.js:41
goog.global.setTimeout(function() { throw exception; }, 0);
                                  ^
Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "window.angular is undefined.  
This could be either because this is a non-angular page or because your test involves client-side navigation, which can interfere with Protractor's bootstrapping.  
See http://git.io/v4gXM for details"
```

I understand that I need to define rootElement: 'html', in the conf.js file, and here is the following code in my conf.js file

```
exports.config = {
framework: 'jasmine2',
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
specs: ['helpers.e2e.js', 'specs/leases.spec.js', ],
baseUrl: 'http://test.manage.ourApp.com/',
rootElement: 'html',
capabilities: {
  'browserName': 'chrome'
},
//This can be changed via the command line as:
//--params.login.user 'ourApp'
  params: {
  login: {
    email: 'ourApp.test@gmail.com',
    password: 'test'
  }
}, 

jasmineNodeOpts: {
  showColors: true,
  defaultTimeoutInterval: 300000,
  isVerbose: true,
  includeStackTrace: true
},
```

The HTML code looks like this

```
 <html ng-app="ourApp" class="ng-scope">
```

I have tried so many suggestions from the web, and still cannot figure out what it is I am doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is that question mark after the `ng-app` attribute a typo?

Comment: yes it is sorry I fixed it in the edit

Answer (score 2):

In your `protractor.conf.js` file, you should specify the rootElement as a selector that will find the element containing your `ng-app` attribute:

`rootElement: '[ng-app="ourApp"]'`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: This did not solve my issue.  I upgraded from 3.1.1 to 3.2.1, and I started getting the error.  My ng-app directive is on the html tag, and the controller is on the body tag.  Which version was this fix tested against?